# Function: Comparing strings and int values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Based on a dictionary involving (car type, production start year, production end year) I need some help understanding comparing strings and integers in a dictionary that I'm returning.

First one involves returning a new dictionary of data from db (Original Dict) whose production year is between the start and end years, inclusive. Assumes that both years are non-negative integers. If end_year < start_year, the returned dictionary would be empty.

```
def car_years(db,start_year, end_year):
    newdict = {}
    for i, num_years in db.values():
        if end_year < start_year:
            return newdict
        if start_year > end_year:
            newdict.extend
            return newdict
```

Seconds function is returning strings of a dictionary. It builds/returns a
new database with all works from db whose media matches the given media argument.

```
def car_type(db,type):
    newdict = {}
    for i, type in db.keys():
        if i != type:
            return newdict
        if i == type:
            newdict.extend
            return newdict
```

In my tester data, I'm getting a ValueError: not enough values to unpack as well as too many values to unpack and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 390, in test_works_by_years_3
self.assertEqual(car+years(database1(),1995,2016),{'Racecars': [(1995, 2016), (2000, 2005)]})
  File "C:\Users\marti\Desktop\student.py", line 6, in cars_by_years
  for i, num_years in db.values():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: can you please include the stack trace that you get when you run?

Comment: As text, please, not images.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated it. @cricket_007